# PHP code to convert PDF or Word Doc to editable online form

Tags: php, forms, pdf, ms-word, doc

Is there a pre-existing script/class/library to achieve the conversion of PDF to WORD DOC?

I am looking for something where I can pass a PDF or Word Doc that includes "fill in the blank" fields, defined by a string of *_* characters.

For example, the PDF or Word Doc might contain:
This is a test quiz.  During our lecture, we discussed the ***_***.  In 1812, ***_*** purchased ***_*_**.

In this example, I could run this file through a parser, which would recognize that the *_*_ fields are editable and would present those as editable fields either through an HTML front-end or through a PDF form, etc.

Has anyone ever seen this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are existing tools to read a PDF or word document, but to convert it to an HTML form, you would have to write your own code

Comment: Agreed, simply convert your PDF to Word, parse through the text obtained, replace all `_____ ` with `<input>` fields.

Comment: Thanks all.  What if I wanted to retain the PDF as a layer in the background, where the users added notes on the top layer only where ___ were present?  Would I need to convert to Word, identify the X,Y coordinates of ___.  Then instead of using an HTML <input> field, do you know of any javascript or layering tools that could place an editable layer on top of each ____?

Comment: Consider converting the PDF to an image, then layering.

Comment: Excellent.  Now if I can just find someone to build it for mobile and web.  Wish I was proficient enough to do it.  Thanks!